# Is javascript scripting?

Tags: programming-languages

This one goes both ways at this point in my computer science studies... Is it scripting in the same sense as a Python script (for example)?

Are they the same?

I'm learning Javascript at the moment as part of a Web design textbook but at the very start of my programming lessons I got quite far in programming with Python and would like to finish it **IF** it is conducive to Web design.

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can help me here and I'll be sure to vote up the best answer for reputation.

Comment: Don't be afraid to learn a different language. Nowadays, projects in the software industry are often built using many languages. Generally, it is more important to understand the fundamental ideas behind languages, than their minor technical quirks. When you do "get" Python, for instance, you'll be able to move to Javascript by just learning the differences. (It is important, though, that you do learn those, and stop thinking "in Python" and translate to JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript and Python are both interpretive languages (as opposed to compiled languages like Java) with JavaScript being (mostly) a client-side language and Python a server-side language.

You would do well to learn them both, especially JavaScript.

Comment: While this is a reasonable answer, it lacks detail and nuance. There are compilers for JavaScript and Python.

Comment: @reinierpost I disagree that it's even reasonable -- it's superficial, it doesn't address the question of "is it scripting?" and, in any case, the question is off-topic.

Comment: A reasonable definition of *scripting* is *programming in an interpreted language*. Then again, there are very different, equally reasonable definitions.

Comment: I just want to say that tale answered my question, perhaps in a somewhat different structure than what other people want to see, but, still, answered it sufficiently since I was wondering if it was related to web design in any way.